# How to use array filter for both parent and child values in angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript

I have array object i need to use some condition for fetch the data.

```
this.knowledgeData = [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Education",
        "isOtherCategory": 0,
        "isKnowledgeSkills": false,
        "isMyInterest": false,
        "isParentKnowledgeSkills": true,
        "isParentMyInterest": false,
        "subCategories": [
            {
                "id": 96,
                "categoryId": 3,
                "name": "Careers",
                "isOtherSubCategory": 0,
                "isKnowledgeSkills": false,
                "isMyInterest": false
            },
            {
                "id": 97,
                "categoryId": 3,
                "name": "General",
                "isOtherSubCategory": 0,
                "isKnowledgeSkills": true,
                "isMyInterest": false
            },
            {
                "id": 92,
                "categoryId": 3,
                "name": "Home Schooling",
                "isOtherSubCategory": 0,
                "isKnowledgeSkills": true,
                "isMyInterest": false
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Have used filter option to find the datas with satisfied conditions..

```
this.knowledgeData = this.knowledgeData.filter((x)=>{
          if(x.isParentKnowledgeSkills ===true && x?.subCategories?.isKnowledgeSkills ===true){
            return true
          }
        })
```

Its return empty... I need to find the data only the parent and child value return true

result should be like following

```
this.knowledgeData = [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Education",
        "isOtherCategory": 0,
        "isKnowledgeSkills": false,
        "isMyInterest": false,
        "isParentKnowledgeSkills": true,
        "isParentMyInterest": false,
        "subCategories": [
            {
                "id": 97,
                "categoryId": 3,
                "name": "General",
                "isOtherSubCategory": 0,
                "isKnowledgeSkills": true,
                "isMyInterest": false
            },
            {
                "id": 92,
                "categoryId": 3,
                "name": "Home Schooling",
                "isOtherSubCategory": 0,
                "isKnowledgeSkills": true,
                "isMyInterest": false
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

which means output should return the object which is having isKnowledgeSkills is true in child array subCategories

Comment: property `isKnowledgeSkills` does not exist on `x.subCategories`, because `x.subCategories` is an Array. It is property of elements of this Array, not the Array itself. Having said that, it is unclear what filter condition you are after - if there is  a subcategory with isKnowledgeSkills === true, or if all subcategories must have `isKnowledgeSkills === true`, or some other condition

Comment: Adding desired output to the question would help to understand it.

Comment: In this above array object I need to fetch the data which is having isKnowledgeSkills true

Comment: I need to apply the filter option for both parent and child objects

Comment: Have added the example result as well

Comment: You are still not being precise enough. What if: 1. parent isKnowledgeSkills === true, but no child is isKnowledgeSkills === true. 2. parent isKnowledgeSkills === false, but it has children with sKnowledgeSkills === true

Comment: condition is isParentKnowledgeSkills should be true in parent array and isKnowledgeSkills also true in child array

Answer (score 3):

I would go with the following:

```
const filtered = knowledgeData.filter(p => p.isParentKnowledgeSkills)
    .map(p => ({
        ...p,
        subCategories: p.subCategories.filter(s => s.isKnowledgeSkills)
    }));
```

- first filter out parent data with isParentKnowledgeSkills
- secondly, filter out child data

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=43&ssc=9&pln=39&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBA1mEB3ANgUwCYHM0BECGU%20MAvDANoBQMNMA3tbUwEQCWGzAXDAMwA0jJjWZh8AWzRcYzAKIYArsEKtwzAUNpsIAeSgALNACcAwoTRYQhgJ5SADOo3TWEANKJUmHAGU4rFCggpADN8ALQHDS0AWSsASTAoIzRoYNCIcMEhLQAFfEM0BLdkdGw0Hz8AqShDeQzHJwhc-ISY%20MT8lO4QsIisiHkAI1NEi0NWZKkqeqYGacc2Dm4ATgA2XrnhJRHLOMXedY2RcUluZlN8o0CDua1dA0MvQeHzHbtr6a0ij1Ly-0CutJ1DYsZytBJJTowbrpTL1AC%207xmsMO7CkSwA7Ij5lsXtZYnt%20MibqIJFJmABxApGUJqIkfZx3IyPIZmUY2bj2On1T7uEreXx-Ko1IHA4SguLgjpQVJhLm0BFymizUVivZLABMWMiOLZ%20KkhJVwhJJ2kAAkQBIYF5gHoQCAUKwwFhaYaGoyHk9Wa8OVqss4vnyygLKtxqrVfSCIGD2slpQDZcCFfUALqZOGUZMwfAQGCgSBQADclEoeegUL8MYwpHgvM8eEI%20AAdEEK0YABQAB1IAD4YB3G84mgUoAG678AgBKTKNsT4DudnswNvKjSNtcd979FnbMbJbj9rfPUbjCDN1uGNs5ki90-%202s-YMQKdMOETidF0v2tCNlAgLBtlsUErKcgA)

Answer (score 1):

change your if condition

```
if(x.isParentKnowledgeSkills === true 
      && ( x.subCategories.filter((y) => y.isKnowledgeSkills ===true).length )){
            return true
          }
```

Comment: I need to fetch the data which is having isKnowledgeSkills  true

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer...

```
this.knowledgeData = this.knowledgeData.map((i)=>{
          i.subCategories = i.subCategories.filter((x)=> x.isKnowledgeSkills === true)
          return i;
        })
```